# CDF Complex Numbers

Tags: dynamic, complex, gui-construction, cdf-format

I can't enter complex numbers into my cdf file.
I can enter complex numbers in my mathematica .nb notebook, the results change dynamically.
I can enter real numbers in my cdf file, the results change dynamically, too.
But I cannot enter complex numbers in my cdf file! The results don't shift accordingly.

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
(*DISPLAY*)
code = DynamicModule[{nglass1 = 1.55 + 0.43 I, nglass2 = 1.5 + 0.41 I},
  Grid[
   {
    {
     {"nglass1 = " InputField[Dynamic[nglass1]], 
      "\n" Slider[Dynamic[nglass1], {1, 2, 0.01}]},
     {"nglass2 = " InputField[Dynamic[nglass2]], 
      "\n" Slider[Dynamic[nglass2], {1, 2, 0.01}]},
     },
    {
     {"Total = " },
     {Dynamic[total]}
     }
    },
   Frame -> All]
  , Initialization :> (
    total := nglass1*nglass2
    )]
```

Comment: I tried to test this with 11.2 CDF player, but the CDF download manager hangs on me each time I try it. May be due to holiday the server at WRI is down.  btw, you can simplify this more, like this `DynamicModule[{nglass1 = 1.55 + 0.43 I, nglass2 = 1.5 + 0.41 I},
 Grid[{
   {Row[{"nglass1 = ", InputField[Dynamic[nglass1]]}], 
    Row[{"nglass2 = " InputField[Dynamic[nglass2]]}]}
   ,
   {Slider[Dynamic[nglass1], {1, 2, 0.01}], 
    Slider[Dynamic[nglass2], {1, 2, 0.01}]}
   ,
   {"Total = ", Dynamic[total]}
   }
  , Frame -> All],
 Initialization :> (total := nglass1*nglass2)
 ]`

Comment: ... not good idea to use "\n" to align things. Use `Grid` all the way.

Comment: On Enterprise CDF it works. It could work in the free Player, too, if WRI decided to make `InputField[2+I, Number]`  work as expected. Right now `InputField` seems to be "designed" to assume that a complex number is not a number, but an expression. `InputField` needs a complete rewrite anyway; I have tried to use it in a professional setting some years ago and basically gave up: way too trivial and feature-limited (like there is not way to get `ContinuousAction` to do what one wants). I think WRI has basically given up on providing a better really customizable `InputField` function.

Comment: Oh ok thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it fails is that FreePlayer only supports `InputField[_, Number]`, which excludes complex numbers. See input/output section in:

http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html

Here is a simple implementation of a complex input field which works in cdfs. I am open to suggestions about improvements.

```
ComplexInputField[Dynamic[x_]] := DynamicModule[
  {re = Re@x, im = Im@x, active = False}
, DynamicWrapper[
    Grid[
      { { InputField[Dynamic[re, (active = True; re = #; x = re + I im) &], Number]
        , Dynamic@If[im < 0, Spacer[0], "+"]
        , InputField[Dynamic[im, (active = True; im = #; x = re + I im) &], Number]
        , "I"
        }
      }
    , BaseStyle -> {
        ShowStringCharacters -> False
      , InputFieldBoxOptions -> {
          ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> {{All, Full}, Automatic}}
      }
    , Spacings -> {0, 0}
    ]
  , x; If[Not@active, {re, im} = ReIm[x], active = False]
  , TrackedSymbols :> {x}
  ]
]
```

and a test:

```
CDFDeploy[
  "test.cdf"
, DynamicModule[{y = I}
  , Column[{
      ComplexInputField[Dynamic[y]]
    , ComplexInputField[Dynamic[y]]
    , Dynamic@Abs[y]
    }]
  , SaveDefinitions -> True
  ]
]
```

[image]